# API Generation error

Tags: android, api, google-api

I am trying to generate an android key for API access. The problem is that I can't. When following the standard pattern for `SHA-1` fingerprint generation from the command prompt this error pops up simultaneously ... Any ideas on what this might be ??? I did read other posts but was not of much help.

```
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
```

I did what had to be done, pointed the path to the JDK bin file where both the key tool and the jarsigner are .... and also followed the standard command line

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore {path-to-debug-or-production-keystore} -list -v
```

also

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your, problem is here

```
keytool -v -list -keystore C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore
```

You have to give your `keystore.exe` location dont use dirtectly   `{path-to-debug-or-production-keystore}`

Comment: keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\username\.android\debug.keystore" -list -v ... like this ?

Comment: invalid format error ... but i did have some success when i tried this keystore -list -v -keystore <C:\Users\Rakeeb\.android\debug.keystore>.keystore   ... the error that popped up was of access denied

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_13\bin>keystore -list -v -keystore <C:\Users\Rakeeb\.android\debug.keystore>.keystore -storepass android -keypass android`